# PHP redirect to mobile version if user browses to subdomain

Tags: php, mobile, redirect

Scenario: I have a website set up with a php 'Mobile Detect' function. If a mobile device IS detected OR version=mobile (which sets a cookie), they are shown (via php) the mobile version of the page. If a mobile device is NOT detected, OR if the version=full (which sets a cookie), they are shown (via php) the Full version of the site. This all takes place on example.com of my domain.

I want to allow users to force the mobile version of the site (in case they have previously set the version Cookie) if they visit **m**.example.com.

Is there a way to redirect m.example.com to www.example.com **AND** set the version=mobile ?
I tried doing this with my DNS settings, using a URL redirect from the 'm' subdomain to www.example.com/index.php?version=mobile which DOES work for the URL, however when the page is shown, even though the ?version=mobile is in the URL, my PHP 'Mobile Detect' does not pick up on this, and still renders the Full version of the page.

EDIT :: FYI I am on a Linux Server.

Comment: Another way to handle what you're trying to achieve without php or redirects is using http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: @AlexLunix - Can you explain? Thanks :)

Comment: You're probably having cookie domain issues.

Comment: a cookie set from www.example.com  is different than a cookie set from m.example.com

Comment: Takes a url and forwards someone somewhere else, check if they are at m.example.com and forward them to www.example.com?version=mobile http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2):

This is the php code, it is more efficiently if you use htaccess for this

```
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) 
{ 
   echo "<script>window.location='http://m.site.com'</script>";
}
```

Comment: I already have a Mobile Detect. I think you misread my question? I want to redirect m.example.com to www.example.com AND force the mobile version. Normally if the user is redirect from the subdomain they would most likely see the proper version (because of my mobile detection) but I want to force it anyway. How would I use htaccess in your opinion?

Comment: Why don't you `header("Location: http://m.site.com");` ? You could even `setcookie` before.

Comment: @Basti - please re-read my question. The mobile version AND full version are on the www.example.com domain. The PHP detects which version to render based on their device. I want to FORCE the mobile version if they type 'm.example.com' in their address bar.

Comment: Sorry, it's to late for me... when i access your site from my mobile device, you want me to write in address bar www.site.com and in address bar will be changed automaticaly in www.m.site.com? right?

Comment: I was commenting on @Crsr, not your question.

Comment: @Basti for seo.. don't play with header, isn't ok. For script, Don't use header only once on a page, etc... The best practice, javascript, jquery (for without refresh page). Don't use meta refresh (very very bad for SEO)

Comment: @Crsr Don't get what you're saying, but it's unrelated to the question anyway. ;-)

Comment: @basti Come on.. you ask me why don't header("Location: http://m.site.com");  and i explain why i choose window.location

Comment: Your "explanations" are just `The CEO does not like header().` and `It's best practice to relocate using javascript`. The first statement is not explained, and I don't agree with the second one. ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8688/discussion-between-crsr-and-basti)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's too late for this, but I think the problem might be with the cookie. The value of the cookie isn't changed at the moment you set it, its changed later/at the en of the script. So if you assign the cookie the value 'mobile' at the beginning of the script and then your script behaves according to it, it's value might not be yet set to 'mobile'. It's better if you write the value of the cookie in a variable at the beginning and then play with that variable, instead of relying on the cookie. So the cookie first sets the variable to 'full' (default) or NULL from the redirect, but then the $_GET sets the variable to 'mobile' and sends the order to set the cookie to 'mobile', which will be set later. Then the rest of your code should act according to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your pages would have to contain the code for both the mobile and the full version, unless you pull them from a database or other means (think Pretty URLs as an example). Then you can write your code as an IF/ELSE statement.